# How do I get control id of widget in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, controls, win32gui

I am trying to set text in a Text Widget in tkinter using win32gui.

```
def enumHandler(hwnd, lParam):
    if win32gui.IsWindowVisible(hwnd):
        if 'WindowTitle2' in win32gui.GetWindowText(hwnd):
            win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd)
            win32gui.EnableWindow(hwnd,True)
            x=txt1.winfo_id()
            print "id is",x


            if win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(hwnd):
                print "iam in";
            else:
                win32gui.SetDlgItemText(hwnd,x,"displayed in text box")
```

The id is printed but while SettingDlgItemText, it gives error Control Id not found. Can anybody help me?

Comment: It looks like you're mixing up Tkinter IDs (strings used in the Tcl code) and Windows control IDs (32-bit integers used in the Win32 dialog APIs). They have very little to do with each other besides both being ways of identifying things, and you can't substitute one for the other.

Comment: Thanks for the response, any other ways how to get the Control ID of the Text widget.

Comment: I'm not 100% sure, but I don't think Tkinter windows, even its modal dialogs, ever use the Win32 dialog API, so their widgets don't have Windows control IDs to get.

Comment: Actually I need to set some text of Text widget from one tkinter window to other window, any other alternatives for it?

Comment: That's easy; just store the Tkinter widgets in variables and get one's text and set the others. Or attach a StringVar to one or the other and store that in a variable. You don't need any native Win32 code at all for that.

Comment: Its like I have a file abc.py , and the same program is executed twice. Submitting a value of text entry from 1st window(Window1) on button click must display the same value from Window1 in text entry of  Window2.

Comment: If the same program is executed twice independently, then they can't see each other's variables. In that case, your only recourse is firing up Spy++ and figuring out the right WM_* messages and window handles... But if that's the case, why is your app designed that way in the first place?

Comment: I am making a chat application and need to display send through one window in other window. I tried storing the data in a file and if the last line is changed then it should be displayed on next window checking its Window Title.

Comment: OK, so why does that need to be two separate applications? One application can have two `Toplevel` windows.

Comment: Its like, the program client.py are executed on two different times in different command prompt. I just have a Root and haven't used Toplevel.
As the client.py is same for all users, I need to display the mesage sent by Client1 to Client2. They both have same piece of code.

Comment: The OS would have to know that another instance of the program is running by getting a value. The easiest way to implement this AFAIK is to use something that is already running, like an SQL server. Note that SQLite will not work for this as it does not use a server that is always running.  When the program is called, it will increment a field in the database, and subtract one when that program exits.  Note that you could use a regular file, but if a second program is run during the time the first program reads, updates the file, and then closes it, the value in the file will not be correct.

Comment: Thank you for the response, finally got some better answer. Will look forward working on it the way you suggested.
Thanks once again to all.